# Python formatting string functions

Tags: python, function

I have a Python string containing a function such as:

```
function = x1 + ((500 * x3) - (2 / x5))
```

and I want to format this function as:

```
add(x1, subtract(multiply(500, x3), divide (2, x5)))
```

What is the best way to go about doing that? Would appreciate any help since I am new to python!

Comment: start by parsing it into parts and then take the parts and reassemble

Comment: Essentially, you're converting from 'infix' algebraic expression (a + b) to 'prefix' notation [+ab, or add(a,b)].  First, you need to tokenize the string into parts -- 'identifiers' (x1, x3), 'constants' (500, 2) and 'operators' (+, *, /).  Create a stack, and as you're processing tokens, when you encounter an identifier or constant, push it on the stack; when you encounter a binary operator, pop two objects off the stack and print the operator followed by the two objects.  Something along those lines ...

Comment: I was learning how to use stacks in python. I found some web examples that use this command:

    from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

But when I tried using this command, I get this error message back: 

    ImportError: No module named pythonds.basic.stack

I tried google searching where to get this module installed from but can't seem to find it. Any help in identifying where I can get this from or any other way to use stack will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Its not about Python. Its about different notations in writing expressions which, in turn, can be a different way of parsing a properly constructed tree with each leaf be a number and each node an operation.

That been said, you must construct a binary expression tree and then parse it with the "pre-fix" way. In addition, you should replace the information/symbols in nodes with the functions/strings that you want.

More, introductory, info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal